# ASP.NET MVC - Create a Alphabetic link list (ALL , "A-Z" & "123")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When a user clicks on a letter the grid will filter only listing the items with the names starting with the letter they have selected

```
public ActionResult Index(string alphabeticList)
{
    if (alphabeticList == null || alphabeticList == "1")
    {
        return View(db.Documents.ToList());
    }
    else if (alphabeticList == "2")
    {
        //TO DO
    }
    else if (alphabeticList == "3")
    {
        //TO DO
    }
    return View(db.Documents.ToList());
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: why dont you use jquery datatables

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in the ASP.NET MVC and you are doing the correct way. One of the suggestion that i would give is that rather than apply so many if else condition. You can put the filter condition in your data model . For example if you are getting the data from database.

Pass the alphabet in the where like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Column LIKE yourchar + '%'
```

One performance gain you can make by caching the data with all the letters initially and query it from that like this

```
DataTable allData = (DataTable)Cache["mydata"]; 
var filterData  = allData.Where(x => x.Name.StartWith(char));
```

Make your view to accept the dataTable and render it . It can be partial view which will render the data.

You can put the alphabet list inside the form tag and keep a hidden field which keep the alphabet selected.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is through front-end. A powerful tool you can use would be AngularJS. [Here's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) a quick tutorial and demo of what your looking for.

Comment: Angular? For a simple alphabetic filter? That must be what the dictionary gives as an example for "overkill"